# CefSharp does not marshal DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, c#, dom, cefsharp

When I execute js in CEFSharp using `EvaluateScriptAsync()`, I *can* return primitive types like string or array. For example, the following works:

```cs
var result = await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).map(element => element.value)");
if (result.Success && result.Result != null)
{
    dynamic values = result.Result;
    foreach (dynamic value in values)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Value is: {value}");
    }
}
```

But once I try to get a DOM element, either one or a list of, I get `null`:

```cs
var result = await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))");
// `result.Success` is `true`, `result.Result` is `null`
```

I thought that CEFSharp only knows how to marshal primitive types, but object literals also work:

```cs
var result = await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("({ a: 1, b: 'hello' })");
if (result.Success && result.Result != null)
{
    dynamic obj = result.Result;
    MessageBox.Show($"{{ a: {obj.a}, b: {obj.b} }}");
}
```

So it turns out that CEFSharp only doesn't know how to marshal DOM objects.

Why? Is there a solution or workaround out there?

Comment: Return only the data you need from the DOM nodes, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result for examples (bottom of the section for example of using array.map()).

Comment: This is unfortunate, but they don't say that (at least not explicitly). They say that objects can be returned and does not put any warning about DOM nodes. Indeed, even objects like `CSSStyleDeclaration` work.

Comment: If you need to return a complex object graph then convert to JSON then use your favourite .Net JSON library. Javascript is executed in a different process, so returning only what you need is always preferable. Anyone with a GitHub account can edit the wiki, your welcome to make some improvements.

Comment: The problem is that I also need to call methods on the object.

Comment: And I wonder, what's the reason that it cannot marshal DOM objects?

Comment: Use something like `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).map(x => ({ innerText: x.innerText, click:  x.click}));` where click will be of type [IJavascriptCallback](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/T_CefSharp_IJavascriptCallback.htm)

Comment: DOM elements (it's actually anything that has cyclic dependency) cannot be converted currently. The detection bails out early, improvements could be made if your so inclined https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/85/CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core/CefAppUnmanagedWrapper.cpp#L436

Comment: So the problem is cyclic references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly it's important to understand that `Javascript` is executed in the render process. The result of `EvaluateScriptAsync` is effectively a `DTO`, we create an object that represents the result of executing the script.

It's not currently possible to return a [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) or any object that has a cyclic reference.

If we look at `HTMLElement as a specific example it will have a parentElement/parentNode and the parent has children which includes the node itself. You also end up walking the whole DOM tree as well.

CEF has very limited type support for it's `CefV8Value` type, so it's hard to do anything too fancy. See [this](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefV8Value.html).

We could potentially add an extension method that wraps the user script in an  `IIFE` and does some `instanceof HTMLElement` style type checking to return a trimmed down representation of the HTML element. See [this](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/fd46a4c14542eda9bec9f94171b4a47a859565aa/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L1000) for an example of how I'm fudging support for returning a `Promise`.

Comment: When I say tree, in reality it's represented as a graph.

Comment: I've added some examples to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result for one way to return a dom element with attributes

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using JavaScript you can now use [CefSharp.Dom](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Dom) which is an asynchronous library for accessing the DOM.

It's freely available on [image: Nuget]

```cs
// Add using CefSharp.Dom to access CreateDevToolsContextAsync and related extension methods.
await using var devToolsContext = await chromiumWebBrowser.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();

// Get element by Id
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
var element = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlElement>("#myElementId");

//Strongly typed element types (this is only a subset of the types mapped)
var htmlDivElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlDivElement>("#myDivElementId");
var htmlSpanElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlSpanElement>("#mySpanElementId");
var htmlSelectElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlSelectElement>("#mySelectElementId");
var htmlInputElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlInputElement>("#myInputElementId");
var htmlFormElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlFormElement>("#myFormElementId");
var htmlAnchorElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlAnchorElement>("#myAnchorElementId");
var htmlImageElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlImageElement>("#myImageElementId");
var htmlTextAreaElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlImageElement>("#myTextAreaElementId");
var htmlButtonElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlButtonElement>("#myButtonElementId");
var htmlParagraphElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlParagraphElement>("#myParagraphElementId");
var htmlTableElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlTableElement>("#myTableElementId");

// Get a custom attribute value
var customAttribute = await element.GetAttributeAsync<string>("data-customAttribute");

//Set innerText property for the element
await element.SetInnerTextAsync("Welcome!");

//Get innerText property for the element
var innerText = await element.GetInnerTextAsync();

//Get all child elements
var childElements = await element.QuerySelectorAllAsync("div");

//Change CSS style background colour
await element.EvaluateFunctionAsync("e => e.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'");

//Type text in an input field
await element.TypeAsync("Welcome to my Website!");

//Click The element
await element.ClickAsync();

// Simple way of chaining method calls together when you don't need a handle to the HtmlElement
var htmlButtonElementInnerText = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlButtonElement>("#myButtonElementId")
    .AndThen(x => x.GetInnerTextAsync());

//Event Handler
//Expose a function to javascript, functions persist across navigations
//So only need to do this once
await devToolsContext.ExposeFunctionAsync("jsAlertButtonClick", () =>
{
    _ = devToolsContext.EvaluateExpressionAsync("window.alert('Hello! You invoked window.alert()');");
});

var jsAlertButton = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlButtonElement>("#jsAlertButton");

//Write up the click event listner to call our exposed function
_ = jsAlertButton.AddEventListenerAsync("click", "jsAlertButtonClick");

//Get a collection of HtmlElements
var divElements = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");

foreach (var div in divElements)
{
    // Get a reference to the CSSStyleDeclaration
    var style = await div.GetStyleAsync();

    //Set the border to 1px solid red
    await style.SetPropertyAsync("border", "1px solid red", important: true);

    await div.SetAttributeAsync("data-customAttribute", "123");
    await div.SetInnerTextAsync("Updated Div innerText");
}

//Using standard array
var tableRows = await htmlTableElement.GetRowsAsync().ToArrayAsync();

foreach (var row in tableRows)
{
    var cells = await row.GetCellsAsync().ToArrayAsync();
    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        var newDiv = await devToolsContext.CreateHtmlElementAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");
        await newDiv.SetInnerTextAsync("New Div Added!");
        await cell.AppendChildAsync(newDiv);
    }
}

//Get a reference to the HtmlCollection and use async enumerable
//Requires Net Core 3.1 or higher
var tableRowsHtmlCollection = await htmlTableElement.GetRowsAsync();

await foreach (var row in tableRowsHtmlCollection)
{
    var cells = await row.GetCellsAsync();
    await foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        var newDiv = await devToolsContext.CreateHtmlElementAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");
        await newDiv.SetInnerTextAsync("New Div Added!");
        await cell.AppendChildAsync(newDiv);
    }
}
```